# JavaScript if else statement ignored

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean-operations

I have a simple if statement below:

```
function calculateTotal() {

    if (tanksize != 1 || tanksize != 2) {
        var setupPrice = basicPrice + StatPrice() + DigiStatPrice() + IRPrice() + UVPrice() + cagePrice();
        var setupPrice2 = toFixed(setupPrice, 2);

    } else {
        var setupPrice = basicPrice;
        var setupPrice2 = toFixed(setupPrice, 2);
    }


    //display the result at the top of page
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.innerHTML = "£" + setupPrice2;

    //display the result at the bottom of page
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice2');
    divobj.innerHTML = "£" + setupPrice2;
}
```

But when the `tanksize` variable is set to `1` or `2`, the `setupPrice` variable is still calculated by adding the `basicPrice + StatPrice...`etc.

Comment: try using if(tanksize > 2)

Comment: Where are you assigning `tanksize` ? is that a global variable because you're not passing it as argument

Comment: @PamioSolanky the tanksize variable is set in a webpage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
if (tanksize !== 1 && tanksize !== 2) {
```

with the `&&` operator, or

```
if (!(tanksize ===1 || tanksize === 2)) {
```

In your code, you have the first block executing any time the value is not 1 or is not 2, which equates to it always executing.

If the value is `1`, then `tanksize != 2` is `true` so `tanksize!=1 || tanksize!=2` is `true`.

If the value is `2`, then `tanksize != 1` is `true` so `tanksize!=1 || tanksize!=2` is `true`.

In other words, `tanksize!=1 || tanksize!=2` is always `true`, no matter what the value of `tanksize` is.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, so im just a moron. Thanks haha

Answer (score 3):

This statement is always true:

```
if(tanksize!=1 || tanksize!=2){
```

because, when tanksize = 1, tanksize is different of 2

and when tanksize = 2, tanksize is different of 1.

It is not a javascript error, you just need to change your logic to make the right test in the `if`...

Answer (score 2):

Try `if(tanksize!=1 && tanksize!=2){` instead of  `if(tanksize!=1 || tanksize!=2){`

Answer (score 1):

### Your Logic is wrong..

As a matter of fact, OR Operator for two NOT EQUALS is always TRUE ( check boolean table for this) and the conditional statement "if" checks for TRUE or FALSE, hence your code will always return TRUE

Use something like

```
if(tanksize!=1 && tanksize!=2){

  # Your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(tanksize!=1 || tanksize!=2) always will be true by this statement. Change operator || to &&

Answer (score 1):

your first condition is always `true`, cuz for example if some `x = 1`, is different of 2 and vice versa.
so this condition is kind of equal to.

```
if(true) {
  // ...
}
```